# Animation similar to Facebook app header in RN

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-animated

How do I get scrolling animation for header similar to FB? I mean no matter how much you scrolled down, when scroll up the header slides down. I want to achieve this animation with combination.

Here is a demo snack [link](https://snack.expo.io/@mdaslamansari2008/cascading-sliding-header)

Comment: hey, did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/ 
   you can use collapsing toolbar to implement like FB

Comment: I am looking the solution in react native.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could get that with **react-native-animated-screen** you should play a bit with the props and the animated style

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]